# How does printf() function treat the strings returned by functions using global buffers?

Tags: c, string, function, printf, return-value

I have written a small code that prints the current date with a specific format. To return each data of the date (day of the week, day of the month, name of the month, etc.), I use functions of type *const* *char* * that pass the data as a string to a variable that serves as a buffer and then pass the buffer to the main function.

The following code represents the operation of my program in a very simple way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char
buff[16];

const char
*printStr1 (char *str1)
{
    strncpy(buff, str1, sizeof(str1));
    return buff;
};

const char
*printStr2 (char *str2)
{
    strncpy(buff, str2, sizeof(str2));
    return buff;
};


int
main()
{
    printf("%s%s", printStr1("foo"), printStr2("bar"));
    return 0;
}
```

My issue is this: when passing each data to the buffer and returning it to the main function, the last two data are the same (the last data is not printed, instead it is printed what was already in the buffer, that is, the second last data).

This only happens when I use a single *printf()* function to show all the data, as in the example above. If I do not use a buffer to return the data (I directly return the argument passed to the function) or use a *printf()* for every data , everything is executed correctly.

**P.S.**: I tried to solve this using functions like *memset()* to clean the buffer, but it does not work, the only thing I can do is use a different buffer for each data (for each function).

I hope I have expressed my problem well.

Comment: Aside: `strncpy` length should be restricted by the target size, not the source. In any case `sizeof(str1)` is the size of the pointer argument, not the length of a string. You should be using `sizeof buff`.

Comment: `sizeof` doesn’t do what you clearly think it does. And yes, you need separate buffers.

Comment: Also be careful because if the source is equal to or longer than the size provided, then [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) will not add a null terminator.

Comment: So, since in my case the length of the string I'm going to copy is smaller than the size of the buffer, it's more appropriate to use `strcpy()` than `strncpy()`, right?
In this way, a null terminator will be automatically added.

Comment: strncpy is not a "safe strcpy".

Comment: @DonFuhrer safe until the day someone passes you a string that is longer than your target buffer, and you stomp memory. strncpy is limited safety. The safe way to use it is to put a null byte in the last byte of the target buffer and after assert that it is still null. The only safe thing to do is abort the program! There is a security issue if, for example, you used a path name that you had truncated: A malicious user could inject their own file as the trucated name at the truncated location.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides the `sizeof` issue (that you're overlooking because your strings are small), your issue isn't related to `printf`

The code first *evaluates* the arguments, then passes them to `printf`. The last evaluated argument "wins" and `printf` gets the same argument twice.

To use only one local buffer, split your `printf` call:

```
printf("%s%s", printStr1("foo"), printStr2("bar"));
```

could be rewritten to:

```
printf("%s", printStr1("foo"));
printf("%s", printStr2("bar"));
```

once printed the value can change it doesn't matter :)

Since C doesn't have a garbage collector or string objects, you cannot just allocate separate buffers and return them to pass to `printf` else you'd get memory leaks, so in C there's no smart & readable solution for such issues.

That said, in one C project I made, I used a revolving list of strings (several buffers, first in, first out). Make it 10 buffers, and you can use up to 10 arguments in the same function and it will work properly.

Comment: The issue of sizeof was passed to me, I did not realize it.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "The last evaluated argument "wins" and printf gets the same argument twice"? I'm curious, because the arguments are two strings of the same size.

Comment: I find it strange that there is no way to clean the buffer and assign new data or overwrite it with other data, even if it is gross. If we have an array of characters with a fixed length and assign a string that fits in the array and add a null terminator, then we could not put the entire array to '\0' and assign a new string of the same length as the previous one?

Comment: @DonFuhrer I didn't understand your comment. Did you _actually_  understand why you had this issue?

Comment: the last argument which is evaluated (which can be the first or the second depending on the compiler) writes the shared buffer last. That's what I meant.

Comment: Excuse my English level.
I just want to know why the last argument evaluated is the one that is written in the buffer and why this happens when `printf` receives as argument the return value of a function, I'm very curious.

Comment: because the buffer is _shared_. first argument evaluated => buffer write, last argument evaluated => buffer _overwrite_

Comment: "so in C there's no smart & readable solution for such issues." --> I'd suggest use of [compound literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53211250/2410359) as a recourse.

Answer (score 5):

This code:

```
printf("%s%s", printStr1("foo"), printStr2("bar"));
```

is equivalent to this:

```
const char *p1 = printStr1("foo");
const char *p2 = printStr2("bar");
printf("%s%s", p1, p2);
```

or this (depending on the compiler):

```
const char *p2 = printStr2("bar");
const char *p1 = printStr1("foo");
printf("%s%s", p1, p2);
```

Now it should be clear why you're getting the output you get.

Comment: Or, put more formally: All arguments must be evaluated before the function can be called. If those argument evaluations have side-effects that clash with each other, well, that's the programmers problem.

Comment: You could also add equivalency to `printf("%s%s", buff, buff);`

Comment: Now I see clearly what I was doing. My case is the second.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53205086/2410359) good answer, ...

To print `printStr1("foo"), printStr2("bar")` with 1 `printf()`, separate buffers are needed.

Since C99, code can use *compound literals*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PRINT_N 16

const char *printStr1(char *dest,  size_t n, const char *str) {
  snprintf(dest, n, "%d %s\n", 1, str);
  return dest;
}

const char *printStr2(char *dest,  size_t n, const char *str) {
  snprintf(dest, n, "%d %s\n", 2, str);
  return dest;
}

// compound literals -------------v-----------------v
#define PRINT_STR1(src) printStr1((char [PRINT_N]){0}, PRINT_N, (src))
#define PRINT_STR2(src) printStr2((char [PRINT_N]){0}, PRINT_N, (src))

int main() {
  printf("%s%s\n", PRINT_STR1("foo"), PRINT_STR2("bar"));
  printf("%s%s%s%s\n", PRINT_STR1("foo"), PRINT_STR2("bar"), PRINT_STR2("foo"), PRINT_STR1("bar"));
}
```

Output

```
1 foo
2 bar

1 foo
2 bar
2 foo
1 bar
```

Comment: Having heard about compound literals, but I've never seen it in use.
Compound literals are used when you need a temporary object?

Comment: @DonFuhrer _Compound literals_ are valid from their declaration until the end of the block.  `{ ..... CL; /* from here */ .... /* to here */}`

Comment: you could create 1 macro with 2 parameters `#define PRINT_STR(print_function,src) print_function((char [PRINT_N]){0}, PRINT_N, (src))`

Comment: btw why do you need `{0}` ? this is an output it doesn't need to be initialized to 0. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Oui, there any many ways to _carefully_ use a macro here.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The initialization of the _compound literal_ is not useful here, yet initialization is required for a  _compound literal_ as part of its syntax.